# Multiple table relation in one table field (Dynamics NAV)

Tags: navision, dynamics-nav

I have created some field with table relationship property in *Dynamics NAV*.

Now I need to create a field that has several table relationships based on different conditions. Could you tell me how to do this? it´s possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible. In your table field go to properties and find **TableRelation** property. Then press the button with 3 point.

Here in **Condition** property you must define your condition, in **table** column your table to relation and **field** column and **table filter** column are optionals.

Add multiples lines to multiples relations, then save and compile.

Here left you an standard example

[image]